# Running a bundled systemjs typescript app using Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, systemjs, bundling-and-minification

I'm compiling a typescript application using `tsc` and this `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    
    "module": "system",                           
    "outFile": "./dist/app.js",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

The project consists of two files that are bundled into a single file that looks like this

```
System.register("logic", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var Logic;
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            Logic = class Logic {
            };
            exports_1("Logic", Logic);
        }
    };
});
System.register("bot", [], function (exports_2, context_2) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_2 && context_2.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that when I run doing `node dist/app.js` I encounter the following error

```
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Even though `systemjs` package has been installed and included into `package.json` dependecies.

Is systemjs compatible with nodejs? How can I make it working? Is there any alternative to simplify the process of compiling from Typescript, bundling into a single file and then running in Nodejs?